# Change values of struct with overloaded operator []

Tags: c++, class, data-structures

I'm trying to make a custom vector data structure. It will always contain 4 float values. I want to make it accessible via its attributes names, but also through operator [ ], so it could be also accessed with index like e.g. array. It should be editable through operator [ ], like vector or array.
I've done so far this:

```
struct vec4
{
    float* x;
    float* y;
    float* z;
    float* w;

    vec4() : data(4, 0.0f) { Init(); }
    vec4(float x, float y, float z, float w)
    {
        data = std::vector<float>{ x, y, z, w };
        Init();
    }

    float* operator[](int i) const
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0: return x;
        case 1: return y;
        case 2: return z;
        case 3: return w;
        default: __debugbreak();
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<float> data;

    void Init()
    {
        std::vector<float>::iterator start = data.begin();

        this->x = &(*++start);
        this->y = &(*++start);
        this->z = &(*++start);
        this->w = &(*start);
    }
};
```

Is there any more elegant way how to solve this problem?

Comment: Depends what you consider elegant. Note that you probably wanted `*start++` and not `*++start` and also you need to provide a copy constructor/assignment or the `x, y, z, w` attributes will be wrong when you copy this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having individual members and then using a switch statement is pretty much the way to do this.  You don't need the vector though and can write the class like

```
struct vec4
{
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;
    float w = 0;

    vec4() = default;
    vec4(float x, float y, float z, float w) : x(x), y(y), z(z), w(w) {}

    const float& operator[](int i) const
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0: return x;
        case 1: return y;
        case 2: return z;
        case 3: return w;
        default: __debugbreak();
        }
    }
    
    float& operator[](int i)
    {
        // this is safe because we are in a non-const function, so this cant point to a const object
        return const_cast<float&>(static_cast<const vec4&>(*this)[i]);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
struct vec4
{
    vec4() : vec4(0, 0, 0, 0) {}
    vec4(float x, float y, float z, float w) : data{ x, y, z, w } {}

    float operator[](int i) const { return data[i]; }
    float& operator[](int i) { return data[i]; }
    float at(int i) const { return data.at(i); }
    float& at(int i) { return data.at(i); }

    float x() const { return data[0]; }
    float y() const { return data[1]; }
    float z() const { return data[2]; }
    float w() const { return data[3]; }

    float& x() { return data[0]; }
    float& y() { return data[1]; }
    float& z() { return data[2]; }
    float& w() { return data[3]; }

private:
    std::array<float, 4> data;
};
```