# Appropriate generic idiom for type vectorization?

Tags: c++, c++14, vectorization, idioms

Suppose I have a type `T` in C++. It has all sorts of methods, it can be used as a parameter to a bunch of functions etc.

Now suppose I want to work on k elements of type `T`, with k being *known at compile-time* and also *small* (e.g. k=2 or k=3); and with most/all actions being elementwise. Naturally, I could hold an `std::array<T, n>` and  fill my code with loops such as:

```
for(auto i = 0; i < k; i++) { c[i] = foo( a[i], b[i] ); }
```

for a function `T3 foo(T1 a, T2 b)`.

but I want to avoid that. Is there some convenient idiom I could use for working with these vectorized-T's as though they were just T's?

Ideally, I would be able to write:

```
vectorized<T1> a = bar();
vectorized<T2> b = baz();
auto c = foo(a,b);
```

and, based solely on the existence of the above-mentioned `foo()`, that would work. I don't realistically expect to get that far, but something loopless in that general direction would be nice.

Note:

- We're not talking SIMD vectorization here (although that's a potential optimization for compilers to consider).
- C++14 solutions are preferred, unfortunately. C++17/20 solutions are relevant (but would not be the accepted answer since I'm stuck with C++14).

Comment: You can just make a `std::tuple` of these things, and use structured bindings to work with the individual members with zero cost overhead, thanks to modern C++ compilers.

Comment: Maybe overload all your `foo` functions? Would that be acceptable? If not, why not? If yes, is this enough to answer your question?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: 1. Forgot to mention I'm stuck with C++14 for now. 2. Even in 17, what's the benefit of an std::tuple over an std::array of the same length? The latter should be preferable, seeing how all my elements are of the same type.

Comment: @anatolyg: 1. I might not even their source code. 2. Too much work! 3. DRY.

Comment: There is no C++ rule that requires all members of a `std::tuple` to be different types. And it might be true that `std::array` can also be bound, like `std::tuple`, have to check. In any case, you can still roll your own structured binds in C++14 and earlier: `auto &first=vec[0]; auto &second=vec[1];`, and then just use `first` and `second` as discrete objects. You can even assign to them.

Comment: Sounds like what you are asking for is the C++17's structured bindings.  You could use something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67302326/4342498) in C++14.

Comment: I suspect you can implement something to allow syntax like `c = do_it(foo, a, b)`, where `do_it` is a variadic template. I don't have experience in them, so cannot propose anything specific.

Comment: @einpoklum, what about writing down the wrong-but-desired code/call? I guess what you want would be `c = foo(a, b);`. Is it this?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't think that I am, although I suppose that could be part of the solution.

Comment: Anyway, for me _working with these vectorized-T's as though they were just T's_ sounds just like _function overloading_.

Comment: @Enlico: You could rephrase the question as "How can I emulate automatic overloading of all functions for uniformly-vectorized versions of all of their parameters?"

Answer (score 3):

If all you need to do is elementwise operations, and if you are ok with the syntax `auto c = elementwise_invoke(foo, a,b);` rather than `auto c = foo(a,b);`, then you could probably give a look at [`boost::hana::zip_with`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Sequence.html#ga6a4bf8549ce69b5b5b7377aec225a0e3), which allows exactly the syntax in your self-answer, provided you make `std::array` a [`Sequence`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Sequence.html).

I don't know why `std::array` is not a `Sequence` (pretty much like I don't know why `std::vector`'s instance for `Functor` is `#if 0`ed out); however, making it is pretty easy:

From the documentation of [`Sequence`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Sequence.html) you see that the minimal complete definition requires `Iterable`, `Foldable`, and `make`. The first two are already available with [`#include <boost/hana/ext/std/array.hpp>`](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/ext/std/array.hpp), so you only need to customize `make` by implementing `make_impl`:

```cpp
namespace boost::hana {
    template <>
    struct make_impl<ext::std::array_tag> {
        template <typename ...Xs>
        static constexpr
        std::array<std::common_type_t<Xs...>, sizeof...(Xs)>
        apply(Xs&& ...xs) {
            return {static_cast<Xs&&>(xs)...};
        }
    };
}
```

where I've used [`std::common_type_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) to ensure that a `std::array` is constructed which can hold all the inputs.

Obvioulsy you also need to formalize that `std::array` is indeed a `Sequence`:

```cpp
namespace boost::hana {
    template <>
    struct Sequence<ext::std::array_tag> {
        static constexpr bool value = true;
    };
}
```

[Here's the demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/vx7E54eYG)

I have no idea about the compilation time overhead, but Boost.Hana is just great, I believe.

Comment: 1. How is std::array not already a Sequence? :-( 2. Can you elaborate on how to make an std::array a Sequence?  3. How bad is the compilation time overhead for hana?

Comment: `auto c = foo(a,b);` is going to be a problem in almost every answer. That is an unavoidable name lookup of `foo`, in a scope where `foo(T1,T2)` is likely visible. In turn, that means you will need a better overload to match `foo(vectorized<T1>, vectorized<T2>)`. And a library can't add random names `foo`; the set of names is infinite. A template to allow something like `using foo = vectorized_functions<&foo>` is going to be a challenge.

Comment: @einpoklum, I don't have an answer to 1 and 3, but I guess I've answered to 2.

Comment: @MSalters: I'm hoping something like you've suggested could be doable, see my sketch-answer.

Answer (score 1):

A naive sketch of an approach (may not actually compile):

```
constexpr const std::size_t k { whatever };

template <typename T>
using vectorized = std::array<T, k>;

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
auto elementwise_invoke(F f, vectorized<Ts>&&... vectorized_args)
{
    using result_type = typename std::result_of_t<F(vectorized<Ts>......)>;
    return result_type { f( std::forward<vectorized<Ts>>(vectorized_args) ) ... };
}
```

And then we would write:

```
vectorized<T1> a = bar();
vectorized<T2> b = baz();
auto c = elementwise_invoke(foo, a,b);
```

Which is not terrible, but still feels too verbose. Maybe some sort of gadget wrapping a function:

```
template <typename F>
struct vec {
  // ...
  template <typename... Ts>
  using result_type = typename std::result_of_t<F(vectorized<Ts>.....)>;

  template <typename... Ts>
  result_type<Ts...> operator()(vectorized<Ts>&&...) const noexcept(/*etc. etc.*/) {
    return result_type { f( std::forward<vectorized<Ts>>(vectorized_args) ) ... };
  }
}
```

And that will get us to:

```
vec foo_ {foo}; // or auto foo_ = make_vec(foo) in C++14
vectorized<T1> a = bar();
vectorized<T2> b = baz();
auto c = foo_(a, b);
```

Comment: `foo` is a function, not a type, so it does not appear to be a valid argument to `vec<typename F>`. You'd need a non-type template parameter instead. Class Template Aggument Deduction (CTAD) is C++17, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @MSalters: How about now? With some CTAD?

Comment: With C++17, you can deduce the class template from the ctor argument, i.e. `&foo`. That means `vec<R, Args...) > foo` can deduce R and Args.. from `&foo`, and store `&foo` in a `R (*ptrfun(Args...))`. Of course, if `foo` is overloaded, you'll need to specify which foo you want by explicitly specifying `R,Args...`

Comment: @MSalters: Indeed, overloading would complicate things. For simplicity let's assume no overloading. Is my bottom 4-line snippet feasible, in your opinion?