# C++ is there way to access a std::vector element by name?

Tags: c++, c++17, std, stdvector

I am experimenting with a simple vertex class.

```cpp
class Vertex
{
public:
    std::vector<float> coords;
    //other functionality here - largely irrelevant 
};
```

And lets say we create a `Vertex` object as below:

```cpp
Vertex v0(1.f, 5.f, 7.f);
```

I am wondering if there is anyway to assign a name to each element of a vector?

Let's say that each `std::vector` will only ever have a size of 3. I know I can access an element or index of the vector in a way such as `v0.coords[0]` through to `v0.coords[2];`

However, I am wondering if there is a way in which I could assign a name to each element of the vector, ie:

```cpp
v0.coords.x == v0.coords[0];
v0.coords.y == v0.coords[1];
v0.coords.z == v0.coords[2];
```

So that if I was to access the vector, I could access via a name rather than an index.

Is such a thing possible? If so, how do I go about creating such aliasing?

Comment: "*each std::vector will only ever have a size of 3*" - then why are you using `std::vector` at all. You should be using `float[3]` or even `std::array<float,3>` instead

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67302215/change-values-of-struct-with-overloaded-operator

Comment: @RemyLebeau fair enough, but the same concept still applies, can I access each element by giving it a name?

Comment: @HumilityDev no, you cannot assign names to vector elements. The only option for that is to have the vector store a struct/class that has a name as a data member. Which is overkill for what y are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @NathanOliver I want each element to be contiguous in memory though.

Comment: If "each std::vector will only ever have a size of 3" and you want to give each element a name, you are possibly describing a simple `struct`.

Comment: @HumilityDev Why?  While it's not guaranteed, there isn't a compiler I have used that would not have all the of members right next to each other in memory.

Comment: @DrewDormann I think you're right, I may be over complicating the problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver ahh ok. Sorry, I am new to all this. I am simply doing a hobby project to replicate how common graphics API work under the hood to learn how they work, but of course as I am not using the common API's I am having to run it all on the CPU. I am trying to pay attention to how memory continuity works etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is anyway to assign a name to each element of a vector?

No, there is not.  At least, not the way you want.

I suppose you *could* use macros, eg:

```cpp
#define coords_x coords[0]
#define coords_y coords[1]
#define coords_x coords[2]
```

Now you can use `v0.coords_x`, `v0.coords_y`, and `v0.coords_z` as needed.

Or, you can use getter methods, eg:

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    vector<float> coords;
    //other functionality here - largely irrelevant 

    float& x(){ return coords[0]; }
    float& y(){ return coords[1]; }
    float& z(){ return coords[2]; }
};
```

Now you can use `v0.x()`, `v0.y()`, and `v0.z()` as needed.

But really, in this situation, there is just good no reason to use a `vector` at all.  It is simply the wrong tool for the job. Use a `struct` instead, eg:

```
struct Coords
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

class Vertex
{
public:
    Coords coords;
    //other functionality here - largely irrelevant 
};
```

Alternatively:

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    struct
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    } coords;
    //other functionality here - largely irrelevant 
};
```

Now you can use `v0.coords.x`, `v0.coords.y`, and `v0.coords.z` as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that might be the case, I was just hoping it was possible to assign names to indices. I really like the alternative approach you added. I'll accept the answer when SO allows me to.

Comment: You really don’t want to use std::vector for statically-sized small vectors. Use std::array<T,N> at least. Possibly wrap it in something.